# CMake - fatal error with visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I'm receiving a cmake error while configuring with cmake-gui:

```
The C compiler "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
  9.0/VC/bin/cl.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: C:/Users/admin/Desktop/myproject/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:c:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com
  CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln /build Debug /project cmTryCompileExec



  Microsoft (R) Visual Studio Version 9.0.21022.8.

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp.  All rights reserved.

  1>------ Build started: Project: cmTryCompileExec, Configuration:
  Debug Win32 ------

  1>Compiling...

  1>Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.21022.08 for
  80x86

  1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

  1>cl /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D "_MBCS" /FD /MT
  /Fo"cmTryCompileExec.dir\Debug\\"
  /Fd"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\myproject\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug/cmTryCompileExec.pdb"
  /c /TC .\testCCompiler.c

  1>testCCompiler.c

  1>Linking...

  1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'

  1>Build log was saved at
  "file://C:\Users\admin\Desktop\myproject\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec.dir\Debug\BuildLog.htm"


  1>cmTryCompileExec - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)

  ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped
  ==========
```

why can't cmake let the vs compiler find the libraries it needs?

Comment: Likely the compiler variables are not set correctly, try using the "Visual Studio Command Prompt".

Answer (score 0):

I had a rc.exe not-found error on my visual studio 2008 installation. Solved it, solved the abovementioned problem.

Sorry for troubling you.